# Mongoose count skip limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am implementing pagination.

What I am doing is counting the items from collection first & after that count will return. I am then doing another find with skip and limit.

Now I want to assign count to the data returned by 2nd query which I am not able to do.

I tried `toObject()` but I am getting error "`toObject()` is not a function".

I don't want to use any library.

```
ErrorReportModel.find().count(function(err, count) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    utile.internalError(res);
  }
  ErrorReportModel.find().sort({
    date_create: -1
  }).limit(20).skip(query.page * 20).lean().exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      utile.internalError(res);
    }

    // i am doing this at the moment
    var myData = {};
    myData.data=data;

    myData.count = count;

    utile.response(res, myData);
  });
});
```

I want to send the count to client side because I want to display `page_number` buttons depending on that count.

Comment: `toObject()` fails because the returned data from `lean()` is a plain JS object so no need to cast. It's either you completely don't use the `lean()` method and call the `toObject()` on the data returned i.e. loop through the array and convert the Mongoose Document to a plain JS object with the `toObject()` method then you can add the count property.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the value of count you are getting? Will be helpful if you can log count inside the first query result callback.